# Why $R[G]/\ker\varepsilon\cong V_0(R)$, where $R[G]$ is a group ring and $V_0(R)$ a trivial $R[G]$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a group $G$ and a commutative ring $R$. Then we can produce a group ring $R[G]$, and there exists a map $\varepsilon:R[G]\to R$. Moreover, $R[G]/\ker\varepsilon\cong V_0(R)$, where $V_0(R)$ is a trivial $R[G]$-module. The statements above were stated in (ii) in the below picture. However, is this isomorphism a module isomorphism? Is $R[G]/\ker\varepsilon$ a quotient module? If $R[G]/\ker\varepsilon$ is a quotient module, what is the scalar multiplication?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is an $R[G]$ module isomorphism. The augmentation ideal is generated by elements of the form $g-1$. On the other hand,  $R[G]$ is generated by elements of the form $h\in G$. So $gh = h + gh-h = h + (gh-1)- (h-1)$. Hence, mod the augmentation ideal, multiplication by $g$  is multiplication by $1$. OK?

Comment: @peterag Yes, the $\Bbb Z[G]$ issue is my typo, now I edit it! Thanks for pointing out. (And I'm reading your comments of my question)

Comment: @peterag Hmm.. what is the scalar multiplication in the module $R[G]/\ker\varepsilon$? For example, $(r_3g_3+r_4g_4)\bigl((r_1g_1+r_2g_2)+\ker\varepsilon\bigr)=$?

Comment: If $\sum a_g g\in I$, where $a_g\in R$, $g\in G$, and $I=\ker \epsilon$ is the augmentation ideal, then so is $\sum ra_g g \in I$. In particular, $I$ is an $R$ module - so the God-given scalar multiplication by $R$ on $R[G]$ descends to scalar multiplication on $R/I$. In fact, as $R$-modules, $R[G]  = R +I$, because $g= 1 + (g-1)$, and the second term $\in I$ : so, in $R/I$, one has  $ r \cdot (g +I) = r\cdot 1 +I = r +I = rg +I$. In other words, $g\mapsto 1 \mod I$ is  $R$-linear.

Comment: I meant $R[G] = R\oplus I$ (direct sum) as $R$-modules.

Comment: @peterag Thanks for the detail explanation! I'll read it tomorrow (my country's time zone)!